# Is this scalene/right triangle solvable, or too many unknowns?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Working on a project and I need to solve this. Is it actually solvable?

I either need the height AC or angles BAC and CAD. The details of the problem are written in the image along with some examples.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UMC9.jpg)

** Updated image with correct labeling

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, the problem appears underdetermined as it stands, but it is unclear what conditions you are assuming are given.

Fix the bottom two vertices of the triangle, that are labeled $B,D$ in the first figure, and assume that the upper vertex $A$ lies on an upper semicircle with $BD$ its diameter, and $C$ is given by the dropped perpendicular from $A$ onto $BD$. Then $\alpha=\angle BCD=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is fixed by Thales' theorem, but angles $\angle BAC$ and $\angle CAD$ and line segment $AC$ are variable with $A$.

Also, your labeling of the points $B,C,D$ is confused. A line segment never has negative length. So the point given by the dropped perpendicular changing from $C$ to $D$ between the first two figures is not ideal. I would suggest keeping $BD$ as the base of the triangle and labeling the dropped perpendicular $C$ in all cases (so that the base of the triangle in the second figure reads $B\, D\, C$).

Comment: Oops, yeah you are right, i made a mistake there. I have updated the image with the correct labeling.

Comment: Just to clarify, the end goal is to determin the two angles, BAC and CAD. The problem is a real world one, where α, BC, and CD are physically measured. The other values are unknown. I know what minimum and maximum values for AC are, and I can solve it using a for-loop where I increase AC each cycle, calculate BAC and CAD, and compare the sum to α. When i get a match then I have AC, BAC and CAD. But i believe there is an easier way to solve it..

Comment: "Fix the bottom two vertices of the triangle, that are labeled B,D in the first figure, and assume that the upper vertex A lies on an upper semicircle with BD its diameter, and C is given by the dropped perpendicular from A onto BD. Then α=∠BCD=π2 is fixed by Thales' theorem, but angles ∠BAC and ∠CAD and line segment AC are variable with A." Does this not mean that AC<BD/2? If that s the case then it wont work, as in my situation AC>BD/2

Comment: any other advice? Perhaps you could explain what you mean in more detail? I dont quite understand what you mean, and when I try to draw it your explanation doesnt seem to work?